# 2 m meteor scatter FM voice freq?

Tags: propagation, vhf, dx

What frequency should I use to try and make meteor scatter contacts on 2m FM tonight, with a nice meteor storm coming?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not a FM calling frequency for this sort of thing.

FM requires good signals, and meteor scatter is very weak and intermittent when it exists at all.

The meteor scatter crowd is mostly digital now.

Most have all mode (SSB) radios hooked to their computer through some kind of sound card A/D interface and are using the [free WSJT software](http://www.physics.princeton.edu/pulsar/K1JT/) written by Nobel prize winning physicist Joe Taylor K1JT.  This software has esoteric modes that can deal with short lived paths or very weak signals in meteor scatter, and very weak slow signal modes for EME, and below the noise HF propagation.  The messages exchanged are very short, typically only callsigns, R's, or maybe a single number for a report.

There is an online hangout for Meteor Scatter Enthusiasts at [Ping Jockey](http://www.pingjockey.net/cgi-bin/pingtalk).